# Getting Data From C Buffer Pointer in Swift

Tags: c, swift, pointers

I am attempting to write an app in Swift that uses this library for playing MOD music files: https://github.com/martincameron/micromod/tree/master/ibxm-ac

The library has a method called replay_get_audio that takes in, alongside the actual data to be processed (replay and mute), an int pointer to a buffer where audio data should be written to (mix_buf):

```c
int replay_get_audio( struct replay *replay, int *mix_buf, int mute )
```

The problem is that no matter what I do, I can't seem to access the data that gets written to this buffer in Swift. It's showing up as an array of zeroes in the variable inspector when I convert the bufferPointer to the data to an array:

```swift
let dataSize = Int(calculate_mix_buf_len(44100)) // 14040 is the output for my mod file - this is the necessary memory allocation amount for mix_buf according to the library
                
let mixBufDataPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>.allocate(capacity: dataSize)
                
let resultingNumSamplesWrittenToMixBuf = replay_get_audio(replay, mixBufDataPointer, 0) // The function outputs the number of samples written to mixBuf - it is returning 882 for my mod file, so I assume it is writing the data successfully
                
let mixBufBufferPointer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: mixBufDataPointer, count:dataSize)

let arrayDataForMixBuf = Array(mixBufBufferPointer) // An array of 14040 Int32s - all with the value of 0...as if the data is not being written
```

If I manually write a value to, say, mixBufDataPointer[1], I can see it shows up in the arrayDataForMixBuf, so I know the reading using mixBufBufferPointer and the associated array conversion are working correctly. The issue appears to be where the library writes into the mixBufDataPointer.

Am I missing something? I'm completely new to pointers in Swift so this is all new to me.

Comment: The swift code you show looks fine. The problem is somewhere else, maybe in `replay_get_audio`. For a test you can replace `replay_get_audio` with your own C code, that just writes some data. This will then show up on Swift side.

Comment: Variable inspector in XCode sometimes show zeros even if there is another value in memory. It is known bug. Try to print value of your buffer to log and check it there.